# What type of searches can employers perform on Careers?

Tags: discussion, jobs, search

When searching on Careers, I'm assuming that employers can search based on the tags that appear in the favourites/likes/dislikes fields, and also narrow this down by location.

What other types of searches can be performed, and what bits of the CVs can be searched? For example, do the free-text bits of the CV get searched using a text search? If so, is this done using the same search routine as on SOFU?

Comment: I think a _lot_ more info about the employer's perspective of the system would be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could post a screenshot, but the search UI is in a lot of flux. Easiest to just register a new OpenID (remember, you *cannot* be both a CV holder and employer on the same OpenID) and try the employer search side yourself -- it's free to go in and see search counts.

Comment: Screenie!!!!!!!

Comment: I've tried the search as you suggest. When searching for skills, it seems to do a tag-based search matching on what people have tagged in their CVs, not a free text search of the entire CV. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, that is correct -- skills is just tags